# Why can't I access an Excel file with pandas on VSCode

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas on my vscode, but when I want to access an excel file with pandas.

I get an error

```
" Unicodescape ' codec can't decide bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uxxxxxxx escape
```

Comment: You have to include more details about your problem. Check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you must always include what code or statement is causing the trouble, and also add a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should also copy-paste the errors. There is at least one typo in this one, so it appears you typed it manually. A complete+accurate error traceback is important for people to help effectively.